# Bootstrap tabs and jquery ui don't work on Tablet

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, tabs, tablet

I use this code in my php project the tabs work fine on PC but on tablet it doesn't work at all. Clicking any of the links doesn't trigger any action

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" 
data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" 
data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Then I replaced it with default jquery ui tabs code

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante. </p>
</div>                               
</div>
```

but still doesn't work at all though I have a range slider working after attaching

```
jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a conflict with another jQuery code. Solved.